# Is there an "Add Page" hook?

Tags: hooks

I'm looking for the action hook corresponding to the click on the "Add page" link. Any idea?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to target the admin page that displays the post editor, you'll likely need to hook to two places whether it's for a script or style.

You'd use the top two for scripts and the bottom two for styles.

```
// Script action for the post new page    
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'example_callback' );

// Script action for the post editting page    
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'example_callback' );

// Style action for the post new page    
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'example_callback' );

// Style action for the post editting page 
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-post.php', 'example_callback' );
```

If you wanted to target a particular post type, simply global `$post_type` inside your callback function, like so..

```
function example_callback() {
    global $post_type;
    // If not the desired post type bail here.
    if( 'your-type' != $post_type )
        return;

    // Else we reach here and do the enqueue / or whatever
}
```

If you're enqueuing scripts(not styles) specifically there is a hook that runs earlier called `admin_enqueue_scripts` which passes on the hook as the first arg, so you could also do it like this for scripts..(if you were hooking onto `admin_enqueue_scripts` instead of the two `admin_print_scripts` actions above).

```
function example_callback( $hook ) {
    global $post_type;

    // If not one of the desired pages bail here.
    if( !in_array( $hook, array( 'post-new.php', 'post.php' ) ) )
        return;

    // If not the desired post type bail here.
    if( 'your-type' != $post_type )
        return;

    // Else we reach here and do the enqueue / or whatever
}
```

These hooks exist exactly for this type of thing, you shouldn't need to fire things as early as `admin_init` unless your specific use case dictates a requirement to. If you're unsure, chances are you don't need to fire your code that early.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the admin_init hook and add you conditionals to page something like

```
add_action('admin_init','load_my_code');
function load_my_code() {
  global $typenow;
  if (empty($typenow) && !empty($_GET['post'])) {
    $post = get_post($_GET['post']);
    $typenow = $post->post_type;
  }
  if (is_admin() && $typenow=='page') {
    //do your stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks that will not do what I need (my question was not precise enough I guess) but it's still usefull